# WalletConnect modal error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'importKey')

Tags: web3js, wallet-connect

When running on localhost, I am able to open the WalletConnect modal and scan the QR code and there is no error. However, when I have my app hosted on a VM (Ubuntu 20.04), after opening the WalletConnect modal and when the QR code displays, I get the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'importKey')
    at browserImportKey (browser.ts:44:1)
    at browserAesEncrypt (browser.ts:59:1)
    at Module.aesCbcEncrypt (aes.ts:8:1)
    at Module.encrypt (index.ts:49:1)
    at async WalletConnect._encrypt (index.ts:1172:1)
    at async WalletConnect._sendRequest (index.ts:790:1)
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?